# Glib HashTable not inserting correctly

Tags: c, hashtable, glib

I have a file with the following structure :

```
finance
www.lemonde.fr 4
|
Brexit:
www.lemonde.fr 2
|
divorce
www.lemonde.fr 2
www.lequipe.fr 8
|
amiable
www.lemonde.fr 2
|
rupture
www.lemonde.fr 2
www.leparisien.com 3
www.lequipe.fr 2
|
Economie
www.lemonde.fr 1
|
Entreprises
www.lemonde.fr 2
www.laposte.fr/particulier 1
|
xiti
www.laposte.fr/particulier 1
|
```

The file is a lot bigger in reality, these are the last lines.

My goal is to load this file in an hash table.
The key would be the first word of each block.
The value would be a pointer to this structure :

```
typedef struct wordInfo {
  char **urls_list;
  int *nbOccurence;  
  int size; 
} wordInfo;
```

main function :

```
int main(){
  GHashTable *hash = loadIndex("index.txt");
  printf("Nombre de clé dans la table: %d\n", g_hash_table_size(hash));

  g_hash_table_foreach(hash, (GHFunc)iterator, "Cle: %s, Value: %p\n");

  wordInfo* x = g_hash_table_lookup(hash, "xiti");
  if(x == NULL){
    printf("NULL\n");
  }

  printf("Taille: %d",x->size);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < x->size ; i++){
    printf("Lien: %s\n", (x->urls_list)[i]);
  }

  g_hash_table_destroy(hash);
  return 0;
}
```

The function loading the file, loadIndex():

```
GHashTable* loadIndex(char *filename){

  FILE *f=fopen(filename,"r");
  GHashTable* hash = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);

  char *word=malloc(100);
  while(fgets(word,100,f)!=NULL) { // reading a word
    char *aux=strchr(word,'\n'); // removes the trailing \n
        aux[0]='\0';


    // we make a structure for the wod we just found
    wordInfo *x = g_malloc(sizeof(wordInfo));
    x->urls_list = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    x->size = 0;
    x->nbOccurence = malloc(sizeof(int)*100);

    char *line = malloc(100);
    while(fgets(line,100,f)!=NULL){ //read urls for the found word
      if(!strcmp(line,"|\n")){ // until we find character |
        break;
      }
      char *url = strtok(line," ");
      char *occ = strtok(NULL," ");
      x->urls_list[x->size] = malloc(strlen(url));
      strcat(x->urls_list[x->size],url);
      x->nbOccurence[x->size] = atoi(occ);
      x->size += 1;
    }
  char* key;
  key = g_strdup(word);
    g_hash_table_insert(hash, key ,(wordInfo*)x);
  }
  return hash;
}
```

The foreach output is :

```
Cle: xiti, Value: 0x978b40
Cle: xiti, Value: 0x687e60
Cle: xiti, Value: 0xb23830
Cle: xiti, Value: 0x86b1f0
Cle: xiti, Value: 0x81e890
Cle: xiti, Value: 0x9df7c0
Cle: xiti, Value: 0x6b0330
Cle: xiti, Value: 0x9eef10
```

As you can see, i don't have different word as keys but only the last one in the file.Also I don't understand how i can have multiple times the same key, isn't it suppose to contain unique keys ?

Comment: Just based on a quick skim, lines like `wordInfo *x = g_malloc(sizeof(wordInfo*));` are a problem.  You're asking malloc to allocate enough room for a pointer to wordInfo (probably either 4 or 8 bytes), not an entire wordInfo (probably 12 or 20 bytes).  It should be `wordInfo *x = g_malloc(sizeof(wordInfo));`.  You may also want to consider using `g_new` (and cranking up the compiler warnings), which casts the result to the correct type so the compiler can catch errors like this: `wordInfo *x = g_new(wordInfo, 1);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I edited the code, but as expected, it doesn't change the problem. I have the feeling i'm getting something wrong about how i should use hashtable but i can't figure it out.

Comment: There are still two broken malloc calls… `malloc(sizeof(char*)*100)` returns `char**` not `char*`, and `malloc(sizeof(int*)*100)` returns `int**` not `int*`.  Once that's done, you should focus on eliminating code from your test case.  Does parsing work as expected? If so, replace it with an array of structs or something.  Keep eliminating whatever you can until eliminating something fixes the problem, then at least you'll know *where* the problem is.

Comment: I missed those one, thank you. I edited the code. Before inserting in the hashtable, i print added word and it seems to be what i expect. But when i foreach in the main, all keys are the last word.

Comment: You should diagnose memory management problems like this using `valgrind`’s [`memcheck`](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#memcheck) tool.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : i had to use g_strdup to make the key, adding a char* as a key doesn't work. I edited the code